# Math calculation refactoring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here's the [**full source**](https://github.com/bevacqua/ponyfoo/blob/master/src/frontend/js/plugin/jquery.readingTime.js) to a plugin I'm developing, the relevant code I want to refactor is:

```
function measure($element, $bubble){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        viewportHeight = $window.height(),
        readableTop = $element.position().top,
        readableHeight = $element.height(),
        readableBottom = readableTop + readableHeight,
        scrollHeight = viewportHeight / readableHeight * viewportHeight,
        progress = (scrollTop - readableTop) / (readableHeight - viewportHeight),
        total = getTotalMinutes($element),
        remaining = Math.ceil(total - (total * progress)),
        distanceProgress = (scrollTop - readableTop) / readableHeight,
        distanceLiteral = readableTop + distanceProgress * readableHeight + viewportHeight / 2 - $bubble.height() / 2,
        distance = Math.max(readableTop, Math.min(distanceLiteral, readableBottom));

    return {
        remaining: remaining,
        progress: progress,
        distance: distance
    };
}
```

How might I make this calculation more understandable? I'm not terribly good at math, so I got there by trial and error, pretty much.

Now I'd like to refactor into something more readable or at least trim the repetitive nonsense, but I have no clue where to start.

Could you lend me a hand or give me any advice on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly in terms of code readability, you want to break down a function like this into it's core parts. Additionally, to reduce repetitive behavior you could make it more of a prototype and use some object oriented style to get to your result without a block of math.

**Things to Consider**

- [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter) -
  Passing into your function only what you need and not entire objects.
- Breaking your function into segments, why not use methods to
  systematically get to your answer? Easily readable/maintainable.
- Reduce the amount of variable creation, you dont need to set each
  value to a new variable when one is already passed in from the
  function arguments. Law of Demeter helps here, too.
- Keeping your code expandable.

Here's an example of a function that follows the three above rules, a simple example that leaves you to put in your mathematics.

**Example**

```
var measure = function(elementHeight, elementPositionTop, bubbleHeight) {
    var remaining = 0, progress = 0, distance = 0;

    return {
        init: function() {
            measure.buildRemaining();
            measure.buildProgress();
            measure.buildDistance();
        },
        buildRemaining: function() {
            remaining = elementHeight * bubbleHeight;
        },
        buildProgress: function() {
            progress = remaining / 2.5;
        },
        buildDistance: function() {
            distance = (elementPositionTop - progress) + remaining;
        },
        result: function() {
            measure.init();
            return {
                remaining: remaining,
                progress: progress,
                distance: distance
            }
        }
    }
}($element.height(), $element.position().top, $bubble.height());
```

**Accessing the Function**

```
measure.result();
```

**Returns**

```
Object { remaining=5850, progress=2340, distance=3582 }
```